# Accessing and extracting Data Frame Results - R.NET

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I run a `R script` from `C#` and get the results in a `dataframe` as :

```
var OUTPUT = engine.GetSymbol("detail.dt").AsDataFrame();
```

`OUTPUT dataframe` has let's say 3 columns as:

```
NAME Month Rate 

Rob 1 100

Rob 2 150

Rob 3 500

Ned 1 200

Ned 2 500

Sansa 1 500

Sansa 2 1000
```

I can extract individual column values as :

```
var Name = OUTPUT[0].AsEnumerable().ToList();
var Month = OUTPUT[1].AsNumeric().ToList();
var Rate = OUTPUT[2].AsNumeric().ToList();
```

My question is instead of extracting column by column values, I basically want to extract `Month` and `Rate` if user asks for "`Rob`" or "`Sansa`".
How do I extract `Month` and `Rate` **values** for a given`Name`?
Is there a better and faster way?

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the data.frame.  Name appears to be duplicated in your data, but here's how you can get one of them:

```
string userInput = "Rob";
int myMonth = 0;
int myRate = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < OUTPUT.RowCount; ++i)
{
  if (OUTPUT[i, 0].ToString() == userInput) {
    myMonth = Convert.ToInt32(OUTPUT[i, 1].ToString());
    myRate = Convert.ToInt32(OUTPUT[i, 2].ToString());
    break;
  }
}
```

If you need all of them, get rid of the break statement, and pile them into a list or whatever data structure that suits you.